# Salesforce enhanced domains redirection with Apex Rest Resource

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, restresource, enhanced-domains

I have a salesforce rest resource I built which works perfectly. We are in the middle of switching to enhanced domains and there is a problem we are facing.

I have an iOS app on the app store and we have the non enhanced domain url hard coded in app.

for example we have the non enhanced domain at "https://company.secure.force.com/service/services/apexrest/data"

this is a fake url but its close. I can hit this end point in the app and all works good. Once we convert to enhanced domains we have this new url
"https://company.my.salesforce-sites.com/service/services/apexrest/data"

Switching to this, the app will not get data for a short period of time for apple to review and approve the changes which will update the url.

We have looked into the redirect article from SF found here https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_security_domains_redirect_forcecom_sites.htm&release=238&type=5
and we have this implemented in a sandbox. When we search the non enhanced domain in the web browser we successfully get redirected to the new enhanced domain. When we hit the non enhanced domain via postman, we get this error(screen shot below) and it does not redirect us.

Is there a way to have redirects work for apex Rest Resources that are made publicly available?
[image]